# zsh profile not working on Iterm2

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, iterm

I have installed `oh-my-zsh` and `Iterm2` but when I change my theme to Agnoster nothing changes. Here's my `.zshrc` file:

```
export ZSH=/Users/{username}/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
plugins=(
  git
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

But my Iterm2 terminal still looks the same

Edit: `echo $SHELL` outputs `/bin/zsh`

Comment: could you check `echo $SHELL` in terminal and show the output?

Comment: @aleksey - it outputs `/bin/zsh`

Comment: have you tried to `source ~/.zshrc` explicitly?

Comment: I did run `source ~/.zshrc`, closed Iterm2 and then started it again; but nothing changed still

Comment: Sorry, seems I can't help you. Last question, what is your zsh version?

Comment: Appreciate you trying :-) zsh version is 5.4.2

Comment: Are you actually *running* `zsh` in your terminal? It's possible for iTerm2 to be configured to run a command other than your default login shell.

Comment: @chepner - If i look in `Preferences > General` I can see a `Command` option that is selected to be `Login Shell`. I presume that's what you are referring to?

Comment: What's your output for `setopt xtrace` ?